# Is there any .NET open source desktop media player?

Tags: .net, open-source, media-player

I want to customize my own media player, but I would rather do it in C#. There is any .NET open source media player, so I will not start from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also look at [Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/). It's probably the most famous customizable media player. Regrettably, there isn't a binary installer for Windows currently, but soon...

Answer (score 1):

[Muine](http://muine-player.org/wiki/Main_Page)